# Nested webflux routing always goes with the route on the top

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

Can anyone tell me in this example of routes everytime I type ex: /api/person/1, etc it all goes to /api/person? No matter which method I choose, it always goes with /api/person.

```
@Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> monoRouterFunction(PersonService personService) {

      return  RouterFunctions
                .nest(path("/api/person"),
                        route(method(GET), personService::findAllPeople)
                            .andRoute(GET("/{id}"), personService::findOnePerson)
                            .andRoute(POST("/add"), personService::addPerson)
                            .andRoute(PUT("/update"), personService::updatePerson)
                            .andRoute(DELETE("/delete/{id}"), personService::deletePerson));

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike the annotation model, WebFlux.fn is very explicit about routing: ordering and all predicates matter. But the good thing is it's easier to debug and you can set debug points in your predicates to understand why a request is being routed to a handler.

In this case, this `RouterFunction` could be described as:

If the path starts with "/api/person"

1. and the method is GET -> then personService::findAllPeople
2. and the method is POST and path matches "/api/person/{id}" -> then personService::findOnePerson
3. etc

Because the first match wins, a request like `"GET /api/person/42"` will match 1), since it starts with `"/api/person"` and it is a `GET` request.

If you want to change that, you can either change the order of your routes, or change your predicate for `route(GET("/"), personService::findAllPeople)`.

Answer (score 7):

Below code is working fine. I have personally tried in my local. As @Brain told, just add GET("/") for findAllPeople() handler method.

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> monoRouterFunction(PersonService personService) 
{

 return  RouterFunctions
            .nest(path("/api/person"),
                    route(method(GET("/")), personService::findAllPeople)
                        .andRoute(GET("/{id}"), personService::findOnePerson)
                        .andRoute(POST("/add"), personService::addPerson)
                        .andRoute(PUT("/update"), personService::updatePerson)
                        .andRoute(DELETE("/delete/{id}"), personService::deletePerson));

}
```

Sample working application: https://github.com/karthikaiselvan/spring-reactive-mongo

Answer (score 2):

even we can remove static imports, besides if we have different types of media types we can use the requestPredicate like the below code :

```
 RouterFunction<ServerResponse> json = route()
      .nest(accept(APPLICATION_JSON), builder -> builder
        .GET("/{id}", personHandler::findOnePerson)
        .GET("", personHandler::findAllPeople)).build();

    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> html = route()
      .nest(accept(TEXT_HTML), builder -> builder
        .GET("/{id}", personHandler::renderPerson)
        .GET("", personHandler::renderPersons)).build();

return route()
      .path("api/person", () -> html.and(json)) // the default would be the first one(here is html)
      .build();
```

you can find more details in my repository: https://github.com/minarashidi/webflux